# CLLocationManager issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to get a single location and then stop getting notification from `CLLocationManager`.

I do it with this:

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id <GPSLocationDelegate>)aDelegate{
self = [super init];

if(self != nil) {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    delegate = aDelegate;

}
return self;
}

-(void)startUpdating{
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}
```

The issue is that even when I do `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

in `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:`

I still get notification, any idea why it happen?

Comment: MTA let us know if you fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try my solution. I'm build two functionals for handling LocationManger Obj.
The first function is startUpdates for handle start update location. Code look like this :

```
- (void)startUpdate
{
    if ([self locationManager])
    {
        [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [[self locationManager] setDelegate:self];
        [[self locationManager] setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
        [[self locationManager] setDistanceFilter:10.0];
    }

    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

The second function is stopUpdate for handle CLLocationDelegate to stop update location.  Code look like this :

```
- (void)stopUpdate
{
    if ([self locationManager])
    {
        [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

So, for CLLocationManagerDelegate should be look like this :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{    
    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    self.attempts++;

    if(firstPosition == NO)
    {
        if((howRecent < -2.0 || newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 50.0) && ([self attempts] < 5))
        {
            // force an update, value is not good enough for starting Point            
            [self startUpdates];
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            firstPosition = YES;
            isReadyForReload = YES;
            tempNewLocation = newLocation;
            NSLog(@"## Latitude  : %f", tempNewLocation.coordinate.latitude);
            NSLog(@"## Longitude : %f", tempNewLocation.coordinate.longitude);
            [self stopUpdate];
        }
    }
}
```

Inside this function above, i'm correct only the best location for update location. I hope my answer will help, Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the reason of your problem is in distance filter. As docs say:

`Use the value kCLDistanceFilterNone to be notified of all movements. The default value of this property is kCLDistanceFilterNone.`
So you just have what you've set - continuous updates.